# SSL user authentication not working in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, openssl

I'm facing a problem with authenticating clients through their ssl certificates which seems similar to a lot of problems I found throughout the net - unfortunately to no solution.

Setup is: apache 2.2, mod_ssl, openssl on Debian linux. I have a client using a Globalsign PersonalSign certificate to authenticate. I have setup SSLCACertificatePath I think correctly since apache debug tells me:

```
[Thu May 10 15:31:35 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(1196): CA certificate: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
[Thu May 10 15:31:35 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(1196): CA certificate: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign PersonalSign 1 CA - G2
[Thu May 10 15:31:35 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(1196): CA certificate: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign PersonalSign 1 CA - G2
[Thu May 10 15:31:35 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(1196): CA certificate: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
```

I don't know why both certificates are twice in this list. Hashes are symlinked correctly via c_rehash utility.

Now the client authenticates (I copy the what I think are relevant entries from the debug log):

```
Certificate Verification: depth: 1, subject: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign PersonalSign 1 CA - G2, issuer: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
Certificate Verification: Error (20): unable to get local issuer certificate
OpenSSL: Write: SSLv3 read client certificate B
OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv3 read client certificate B
Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?
```

which to my limited understanding means he is failing to get the issuer certificate for the intermediate *GlobalSign PersonalSign 1 CA - G2* certificate. In fact the issuer_hash of this certificate matches the hash of the *GlobalSign Root CA* which is indeed found in the SSLCACertificatePath correctly symlinked with this very hash and mentioned earlier in the log as loaded.

So I'm stuck. Any ideas anyone?

Edit:

If I verify the user's certificate through the openssl commandline utility it works:

```
# openssl verify -CApath conf/ssl.user.crt/ test.pem  
test.pem: OK
```

(*conf/ssl.user.crt* is my SSLCACertificatePath)

Comment: What is the client here? A web browser (which one)? Have you tried connecting to the server with s_client (e.g. `openssl s_client -cert test.pem -connect example.com:443`)?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what versions of software you're running?  There have been occasions in the past where renegotiation has been disabled due to vulnerabilities (see CVE-2009-3555).

Comment: Apache is 2.2.22, Browser is IE9 and Chrome. I haven't tested with the openssl client since I have no access to the client's certificate (it's a customer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. turns out it was a permissions problem:

I have set up a similar setting on a clean Debian Squeeze machine and it worked right from the start. The difference in debug output was:

```
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1321): [client 80.252.98.156] Certificate Verification: depth: 2, subject: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA, issuer: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA 
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1321): [client 80.252.98.156] Certificate Verification: depth: 1, subject: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign PersonalSign 1 CA - G2, issuer: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1321): [client 80.252.98.156] Certificate Verification: depth: 0, subject: /CN=kettensaege@massaker.de/emailAddress=kettensaege@massaker.de, issuer: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign PersonalSign 1 CA - G2
```

on the 'good' side, vs:

```
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1321): [client 80.252.98.156] Certificate Verification: depth: 1, subject: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign PersonalSign 1 CA - G2, issuer: /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
[error] [client 80.252.98.156] Certificate Verification: Error (20): unable to get local issuer certificate
```

on the 'bad' side.

The main difference between the two setups are the permissions for the /conf dir of the apache installation where the CA-certs reside. For security reasons we have the permissions set to 750 and the dir owned by root. Moving the CA files to a dir readable (or to be precise 'executable' to be used in path) made the problem disappear.

So it seems that though mod_ssl claims to read the certificates at server startup it still needs access to the hashed files while running (and having dropped it's root privileges).